# Microsoft Edge driver different element results

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, selenium-edgedriver

I am currently using an automation tool which uses Chrome/Firefox/IE and I want to implement Edge with it. However, Edge seems to return different results from the elements.

Example: Chrome/Firefox/IE return "Username *" and Edge returns "Username *\r\n"

Anything I can do to fix this to make the browsers return the same result?

I am using Release 16299 and Selenium 3.5.1

Also am using this code to call the driver:

```
EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
                options.PageLoadStrategy = EdgePageLoadStrategy.Eager;
                edgeDriver = new EdgeDriver(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DriverPath"],options);

                return edgeDriver;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example, you could identify those element by searching for if they contain the text "Username".  [This post](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/10416/29127) goes into much detail about how, but for your example you can do:

```
//[InsertElementTypeHere][contains(text(), 'Username')]
```

Comment: The problem is that I kindof don't wish to change the whole test cases.. however if its the only way it is no problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing.  You'll have to change something in the test case from what I see (as they are different strings), but changing to contains shouldn't significantly denegrate the tests reliability.